# bash 3.2.25 version of "find"

Tags: linux, find

I wanted to used some time parameters with the find command, and I kept on getting errors on "daystart" and "newermt".

```
 find . -type f -newermt "today 7:00:00" ! -newermt "today 17:00:00"
```

I ran man find top see how to use the parameters properly and it does not have these options on the man page. So I guess I need to update my find. However how do I find out what version of find I am running? When I look find version of bash find on the google search page, I only get ways to find current version of bash not the find version.

Comment: I am running red hat. Is it in your man page, because it is not in mine. and moreover, does not work. I listed how I used it - is this the right way to use it ?

Comment: find . -type f -newermt "today 7:00:00" ! -newermt "today 17:00:00"
find: invalid predicate `-newermt'

Comment: No, I was mistaken. It was added in 4.3.3.

Comment: 4.3.3 is a bash version - so you cannot unzip a new executable of find, you have to release a whole new version of bash - the command find is not independent of the shell  - I would have to upgrade the shell to get the command ?

Comment: 4.3.3 is the version of findutils.

Comment: To clarify: `find` is not a Bash builtin, it's a separate executable, it has nothing to do with the version of Bash. In my Debian `type find` returns `find is /usr/bin/find`; then `apt-file search /usr/bin/find | grep "find$"` yields `findutils: /usr/bin/find`. Next `dpkg -l | grep findutils` tells me what version I have. I don't know Red Hat. You should probably use `yum` or something to investigate what version you have.